# VBA Object doesn't support this property or method when using SaveAs funtion

Tags: excel, vba

I'm receiving an error 'Object doesn't support this property or method' on SaveAs line

```
 Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 xl.Workbooks.Open ("s:\Common\Template.xlsx")
 xl.Visible = True

xl.Sheets("Data").Visible = True
xl.Sheets("Data").Select
xl.Range("A1").Select
xl.Range("Table_CBA_Group_Tiered_Inputs.accdb[[#Headers],[ACTIVITY_DT]]").Select
xl.Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
xl.Worksheets("Fname").Visible = True
xl.Sheets("Fname").Select


 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 Path = "S:\Common\"
 Filename = xl.Sheets("Fname").Range("A7").Value
 xl.SaveAs Path & Filename & ".xlsx"
 xl.Close
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: `Excel.Application`, indeed, [does not have](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application(object)#methods) a method `SaveAs`.

Comment: Do you have missing code where you load a workbook into `xl` ?

Comment: @TimWilliams 
Yes, I do. Sorry:

`xl.Workbooks.Open ("s:\Common\test.xlsx")
    xl.Visible = True`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

EDIT - updated from your updated post...

```vb
Dim xl, wb, Path, fName

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("s:\Common\Template.xlsx")
xl.Visible = True

wb.Sheets("Data").Visible = True
wb.Sheets("Data").ListObjects( _
    "Table_CBA_Group_Tiered_Inputs.accdb").Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

wb.Worksheets("Fname").Visible = True
wb.Sheets("Fname").Select

Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'this doesn't affect your `xl` instance...
Path = "S:\Common\"
fName = wb.Sheets("Fname").Range("A7").Value
xl.SaveAs Path & fName & ".xlsx"
xl.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'see above...
'xl.Quit
```

Comment: Will it work without `, xlOpenXMLWorkbook`?

Comment: @VBasic2008 - pretty sure I don't typically specify the format if I'm saving as the same type.

Comment: When I try that it messes up the rest of my code that I'm using to refresh my tables. I tried switching all of the xl to wb and I end getting an error on the Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh line:

 `xl.Sheets("Data").Visible = True
 xl.Sheets("Data").Select
    xl.Range("A1").Select
    xl.Range("Table_CBA_Group_Tiered_Inputs.accdb[[#Headers],[ACTIVITY_DT]]").Select
    xl.Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    xl.Worksheets("Fname").Visible = True
    xl.Sheets("Fname").Select`

Comment: If you have code to add, it's best to edit your question and add it there.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to using stackoverflow. Just updated my question to make it easier to read @TimWilliams

Comment: Are you running this code from Excel, or some other application?

Comment: Yes I’m running this from excel

Answer (score 0):

### New Instance of Excel

- Opens a new 'invisible' instance of `Excel`. In it, it opens a workbook, runs a query, and saves the workbook with a different name. Closes the workbook and the `Excel` instance.
- Without the message box, it would be like nothing happened.
- Not tested.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub testNewApp()
    
    Const FolderPath As String = "S:\Common\"
    Const trgAddress As String _
        = "Table_CBA_Group_Tiered_Inputs.accdb[[#Headers],[ACTIVITY_DT]]"
    
    Dim Success As Boolean
    
    On Error GoTo NewAppError
    With New Application
        '.Visible = False ' False is default.
        With .Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & "Template.xlsx")
            With .Worksheets("Data")
                .Visible = xlSheetVisible
                .Range(trgAddress).ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh _
                    BackgroundQuery:=False
            End With
            Dim FilePath As String
            With .Worksheets("Fname")
                .Visible = xlSheetVisible
                FilePath = FolderPath & .Range("A7").Value & ".xlsx"
                ' Ensure that "Fname" is the active sheet
                ' when the new file is opened.
                .Activate
            End With
            ' Overwrite without confirmation.
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            .SaveAs FilePath
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            .Close
        End With
        Success = True
SafeExit:
        .Quit
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
     
    If Success Then
        MsgBox "Workbook created.", vbInformation, "Success"
    Else
        MsgBox "Workbook not created.", vbCritical, "Failure"
    End If
    
    Exit Sub

NewAppError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit

End Sub
```